# draw a vertical line in a videocapture opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

i followed a tutorial about facedetection using c++ and visual studio 2012 it worked well for , but then i wanted to add vertical lines to the video capture (from webcam) but nothing happened i dont know what exactly went wrong, i could really appreciate your help with this .here is the code i'm working on :

```
int main() {

VideoCapture cap(0);        // Open default camera
Mat frame;
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
line(frame, Point(frame.cols / 2 + 1, 0),
    Point(frame.cols / 2 + 1, frame.rows - 1),
            Scalar(255, 0, 128));
// Load preconstructed classifier
face_cascade.load("C:\\opencv24\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

while (cap.read(frame)) {
    detectFaces(frame);       // Call function to detect faces
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)     // Pause key
        break;
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

after some modification in the code i finally arrived to get the line drawn ,here is the running code

```
while (cap.read(frame)) {
           // Call function to detect faces


    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    //cvtColor(frame, frame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
   cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
line(frame, Point(frame.cols / 2 + 1, 0),
    Point(frame.cols / 2 + 1, frame.rows - 1),
          Scalar(255, 0, 0));


imshow("edges", frame);
detectFaces(frame);
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)     // Pause key
        break;
} 

return 0;
```

}